# How to serialize List<object>

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I am writing common functions to serialize the given object and List<object> as follows

```
public string SerializeObject(Object pObject)// for given object
{
    try
    {
        String XmlizedString = null;
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(pObject));
        XmlTextWriter xmlTextWriter = new XmlTextWriter(memoryStream, Encoding.UTF8);
        xs.Serialize(xmlTextWriter, pObject);
        memoryStream = (MemoryStream)xmlTextWriter.BaseStream;
        XmlizedString = UTF8ByteArrayToString(memoryStream.ToArray());
        return XmlizedString;
    }
    catch (Exception e) { System.Console.WriteLine(e); return null; }
}

public string SerializeObject(List<Object> pObject)// for given List<object>
{
    try
    {
        String XmlizedString = null;
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(pObject));
        XmlTextWriter xmlTextWriter = new XmlTextWriter(memoryStream, Encoding.UTF8);
        xs.Serialize(xmlTextWriter, pObject);
        memoryStream = (MemoryStream)xmlTextWriter.BaseStream;
        XmlizedString = UTF8ByteArrayToString(memoryStream.ToArray());
        return XmlizedString;
    }
    catch (Exception e) { System.Console.WriteLine(e); return null; }
}
```

first one is working fine. If I pass any type, it is successfully returning xml string.

CORRECTION: Compilation error has occurred for second one (Error: cannot convert from `List<MyType>` to `List<object>`.

I rewrite the second one as follows which solves my problem. Now it is serializing the given `List<generic types>`.

```
private string SerializeObject<T>(T source)
{
    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    XmlTextWriter xmlTextWriter = new XmlTextWriter(memoryStream, Encoding.UTF8);
    xs.Serialize(xmlTextWriter, source);
    memoryStream = (MemoryStream)xmlTextWriter.BaseStream;
    string XmlizedString = UTF8ByteArrayToString(memoryStream.ToArray());
    return XmlizedString;
}
```

Comment: @afin: maybe you didn't realize, but you shouldn't use `new XmlTextWriter()` anymore. It has been deprecated in favor of `XmlWriter.Create()`. Since .NET 2.0.

Comment: You could check out Fasterflect (http://fasterflect.codeplex.com), which includes a ToXml extension method for objects. It's one-way only and so might not be what you need but it will work for pretty much every object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/Contents/Item/Display/345

The relevant code from the article:

```
private static string SerializeObject<T>(T source)
{
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    using (var sw = new System.IO.StringWriter())
    using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(sw))
    {
        serializer.Serialize(writer, source);
        return sw.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: dead link ... can't get there from here

Answer (score 2):

I have tried your two functions without much trouble. The only thing I changed was this line:

```
XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(pObject));
```

to this:

```
XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(pObject.GetType());
```

typeof() requires an actual type whereas GetType() returns the type of the object.

Comment: @quagland: sorry, my question has been corrected. I got compilation error for second one, since I passed List<MyType> as a input parameter. I need this common function should support all types.